# Is the number of maximal cliques of a planar graph bounded by its number of faces?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

I would like to know if there is any relationship between the number of maximal cliques in a planar graph, and its number of faces?

It is [known](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/119523/clique-problem-for-planar-graph) that for a planar graph $G$, if $H\subseteq G$ is a clique of $G$ then $|H|\leq 4$.

It is also [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Maximal_planar_graphs) that the number of faces $f$ of $G$ is given by $f\leq 2v-4$.

Let $m$ be the number of maximal cliques of $G$.

Does it follow from the  above that $m\leq 2v-4$?

Is there a more precise quantity that describes the number of maximal cliques of a planar graph?

Comment: Is the question about the relationship with the number of faces or the number of vertices?

Comment: Since $f\leq 2v-4$ you could phrase the question either way I guess.

Comment: I believe that every face of your graph can be part of at most one clique. This is if any planar graph can be drawn with only straight lines. I feel like this is true, but I forgot. Do you know about it?

Comment: Ok that is apparently called Fary's theorem. So, I think that with such embedding you can prove that every face is part of most one clique. Then you have $m\leq\frac{f}{3}$

Comment: Not all maximal cliques "come from" faces, so the number of faces is not a bound on the number of maximal cliques. I think it should not take too much work to prove a weak upper bound like $m \le 10v$ or so, but harder to make it tight. (You'd have to think about the tradeoffs between different types of cliques; e.g. if a face is not a triangle, we lose a potential maximal $3$-clique, but now the edges on its boundary have the chance to be maximal $2$-cliques...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we forget about maximality for the moment, then in an $n$-vertex planar graph where $n \ge 3$, the following bounds hold.

**Fact 1.** The number of $2$-cliques is at most $3n-6$.

**Proof.** This is just the usual upper bound on the number of edges in a planar graph.

**Fact 2.** The number of $3$-cliques is at most $3n-8$.

We induct on $n$. For $n=3$, there is at most $1$ clique, and $1 = 3\cdot 3 -8$.

For $n \ge 4$, if our graph has no $3$-cliques that are not faces, then we're done: there are at most $2n-4$ faces, so the number of $3$-cliques is also at most $2n-4 \le 3n-8$. If there is a $3$-clique $C$ that is not a face, then we split up $G$ into two graphs $G'$ and $G''$, formed by deleting the interior of $C$ (in some fixed plane embedding) and the exterior of $C$, respectively. These have $n'$ and $n''$ vertices where $3 \le n', n'' < n$ and $n' + n'' = n+3$; every $3$-clique of $G$ is in either $G'$ or $G''$, but $C$ is counted twice. By induction, there are at most $(3n'-8)+(3n''-8)-1$ cliques in $G$, which is $3(n+3) - 17 = 3n-8$.

**Fact 3.** The number of $4$-cliques is at most $n-3$.

We induct on $n$ again. For $n=3$, we should get $0$, and for $n=4$, we should get $1$.

For $n \ge 5$, suppose our graph $G$ contains a $4$-clique on vertices $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$. We will take *four* graphs $G_1, G_2, G_3, G_4$ obtained as follows (with respect to a fixed plane embedding of $G$): in $G_1$ we delete everything on the same side (interior or exterior) of the cycle $v_2 v_3 v_4$ as $v_1$, and do the corresponding thing for $G_2, G_3, G_4$. Let these graphs have $n_1, n_2, n_3, n_4$ vertices. Then $$(n_1 - 3) + (n_2 - 3) + (n_3 - 3) + (n_4 - 3) = n-4$$ because both sides count the vertices in $G$ other than $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$, so $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 =n+8$. Every $4$-clique in $G$ except the one we found is contained in some $G_i$, and each $G_i$ contains between $3$ and $n-1$ vertices, so by induction the number of cliques in $G$ is at most $$(n_1-3) + (n_2 -3) + (n_3 - 3) + (n_4 - 3) + 1$$ which simplifies to $(n+8)-12 + 1$ or $n-3$.

---

From these facts, we get a weak upper bound on the number of maximal cliques: $$(3n-6) + (3n-8) + (n-3) = 7n-17.$$ This is just a bound on the number of $2$-cliques, $3$-cliques, and $4$-cliques, whether or not they're maximal.

Both Fact 2 and Fact 3 are tight for [Apollonian networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollonian_network), but in Apollonian networks, none of the $3$-cliques are maximal, so those have an unusually *low* number of maximal cliques.

Comment: this definitely answers my question, thank you! is this statement equivalent to: all classes of planar (i.e., isometrically embeddable into $\mathbb R^2$) graphs on $n$ vertices contain $O(n)$ maximal cliques?

Comment: Yes, my answer implies that all planar graphs have $O(n)$ maximal cliques. (I'm a bit iffy on "planar" being the same thing as "isometrically embeddable into $\mathbb R^2$ but I guess if you have some very topological definition of a graph then that could be reasonable.)

Comment: Nice proof. We can also see these results for $3$-cliques and $4$-cliques :   \[1\] S.L. Hakimi, E.F. Schmeichel, On the number of cycles of length k in a maximal planar graph, J. Graph Theory 3 (1)
(1979) 69–86, http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.3190030108, MR519175.    \\     \[2\] N. Alon, Y. Caro, On the number of subgraphs of prescribed type of planar graphs with a given number of vertices, in: Convexity and Graph Theory, Jerusalem, 1981, in: North-Holland Math. Stud., vol. 87, North-Holland, Amsterdam,
1984, pp. 25–36, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0304-0208(08)72803-2, MR791009

Comment: For the maximum number of cliques of $1$-planar graphs, we can see:  J. Pascal Gollin, Kevin Hendrey, Abhishek Methuku, Casey Tompkins, Xin Zhang, Counting cliques in 1-planar graphs,
European Journal of Combinatorics,
(109) 2023, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2022.103654.